# How to get PFUser from array ? [Parse.com Cloud Code]

Tags: arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, pfuser

I have a class called Chat. Its objects have two attributes: "users" and "messages". I want to detect if a message was added to the "messages" array and if so send push notification to all users from "users" array.

This is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(„Chat”, function(request, response) {
    if (request.object.dirty("messages")) {
        var users = request.object.get("users");
        for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
            var currentUserId = users[i].get("objectId");
            console.log(currentUserId);
        }
        response.success();
    } else {
        response.error(„no messages sent”);
    }
});
```

I know how to send push but I have a problem with getting the PFUser objects from "users" array. When I try to print their IDs in console I get "no message sent" error in parse.com logs. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: why don't you use a Relation instead of an Array in your chat class to track Messages and Users ?? You will be able to access the user objects easily via a Relation

Comment: Replace `users[i].get("objectId");` with `users[i].id;`